# Why does curl turn null post arguments into empty strings?

Tags: php, curl

When making a curl post to another script, sometimes I may want to send `null` as the value for certain keys:

```
$postdata = array(
        'userID'        => 0,
        'questionText'  => "Can you answer this question?",
        'time'          => null);

$req = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); 
$data = curl_exec($req);
curl_close();
```

However, the data seems to have changed by the time it is received. Doing a vardump on $_POST reveals that the 'time' value is now an empty string:

```
array(3) {
    ["userID"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["questionText"]=>
    string(29) "Can you answer this question?"
    ["time"]=>
    string(0) ""
}
```

What's going on here? Why is everything a string? How can I perserve the typing?

Comment: What happens when you don't set the attribute at all in the request array?

Comment: It won't be in the $_POST array, of course.

Comment: AFAIK any query to a website will be converted to text and there's no way to represent null in a text so in the end your post data might look like this: `userID=0&questionText=Can you answer this question?&time=`

Comment: Also in what case do you want to send null?

Comment: HTTP transfers text only. Therefore a null value cannot be accurately represented. Why is it causing a problem for you? Do you need to differentiate between empty string and NULL on the receiving end?

Comment: @marekful It's a problem for me, because I use that value in an `INSERT` operation. A null value will not trigger a foreign key constraint, but an empty string will. It's also asking for trouble to have the userID (integer) being converted to a string. Some type safe languages like Swift will scream at you for feeding them the wrong type. There are of course easy hacks/workarounds, but I wanted to ask if there was a better way first. Guess there isn't. LAMP stack has so many issues with typecasting for me...what is the most popular alternative now?

Comment: In an HTTP request you will only ever receive strings. You have to map value types to database fields on the server side. I recommend to use an ORM framework.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm already using a psuedo-ORM framework just in how I structured my code. Never knew the term for it though.

Answer (score 1):

As comments to the original question state, HTTP requests will only ever provide strings.